# How to sum the rows if it has a char value in the row

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have an attendance table like

```
user_name     |   Col  |   col2   |   Col3  |  Col4 + other columns.

person1       |  a     |  3       | 76      | 56  etc.    ---------> sum of row

person2       |  6     |  72      | a       | 13  etc.    ---------> sum of row
```

where 'a' indicates absent, so I need to add all columns in a row and display in the last column i.e. in 'total' in such a way that 'a' should be ignored and sum of remaining columns in a row should be added and displayed in the row of last column

Comment: Why isn't this a numeric datatype with `NULL` representing absent? In fact why do you have 31 columns at all? Just have a table with `empno,date,value` with a row for each attendance record. And what RDBMS are you actually using?

Comment: @MartinSmith is right. A column for every day of the month (what about February?) is wasteful and inefficient. Just record the day(s) the employee is absent as `date`s and if there's no record for a particular day, that just means the employee was in attendance.

Comment: first  your database is poorly designed. one solution is that you need to use case statement and Change a to o and cast into integer to find the sum.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use NULL instead of 'a' but if you use MySql you could use something like this:

```
SELECT
  user_name, Col, col2, Col3, Col4, Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE 'a' IN (Col, Col2, Col3, Col4)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46229/2).

Comment: This isn't going to work (actually DV retracted as maybe it will in MySQL. SQL Server will certainly give an error if you try ` 'a' + 3 + 76 +56 )

Comment: @MartinSmith why you say it isn't going to work? I've added a fiddle, mysql allows you such queries

Comment: @MartinSmith okay the question is marked both sql-server and mysql, i've specified in my answer that it only works in mysql

Comment: Yes I retracted my DV as per edit above. The OP has tagged both MySQL and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

try this in **mysql**

```
     SELECT
      user_name, Col, col2, Col3, Col4, Col+Col2+Col3+Col4 as sum
     FROM
      yourtable
```

this in **sql server**

```
 SELECT
 user_name, Col, col2, Col3, Col4 ,
 case when col = 'a'
            then cast(col2 as int ) + cast(col3 as int ) +cast(col4 as int )
 when col2 = 'a'
            then cast(col as int ) + cast(col3 as int ) +cast(col4 as int )
 when col3 = 'a'
            then cast(col as int ) + cast(col2 as int ) +cast(col4 as int )
 when col4 = 'a'
            then cast(col as int ) + cast(col2 as int ) +cast(col3 as int )
else  cast(col as int )+ cast(col2 as int ) + cast(col3 as int ) +cast(col4 as int)     
 end    as sum_all

 FROM
  yourtable

 group by user_name , col , col2, col3,col4
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cc04/34)

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL this works:

```
SELECT
  user_name, Col, col2, Col3, Col4, 
  CAST(REPLACE(Col, 'a', '0') AS INT)+
  CAST(REPLACE(Col2, 'a', '0') AS INT)+
  CAST(REPLACE(Col3, 'a', '0') AS INT)+
  CAST(REPLACE(Col4, 'a', '0') AS INT)
FROM
  yourtable
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46229/46/0)

Instead of REPLACE you could also use CASE statements.